# linked list and file I/O C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to make a program that allows the user to name a file, and then create that file. My problem came when i needed to error check to make sure there wasn't already a file with that name. I decided to put the file name into a linked list and then each time after one was created it would go through the list to make sure the new filename didn't match any of the previous ones. There are other functions in my code but I am only worried about getting the createDB function to work, right now it just always says the name is already taken and from doing some debugging it seems like it is because my curr variable is always NULL. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class List{

private:
    struct dataB{ //node
        string name;
        int open; //1 if open 0 if closed
        dataB *next;
    };
    // initializing node variables to go through linked list and search
    dataB *head;
    dataB *curr;
    dataB *temp;

public:
    List();
    void insert(string name, int open);
    bool search(string fName);
    void createDB();
    void openDB();
    int menu();
}; //end class

List::List(){
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}
void List::insert(string name, int open){
    dataB *n = new dataB;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->name = name;
    n->open = open;

    if(head != NULL){ // if already things in list put it last
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n; // always puts new node at the end
    }
    else{ // if no list, make new node the start of list
        head = n;
    }
}

bool List::search(string fName){ //return false if no match, true if there is
    curr = head; //start from beginning of list
    bool match = true;
    while(curr != NULL) {
        if (fName != curr->name){
            curr = curr->next;
            match = false;
        }
    }
    return match;
}


void List::createDB() {
    ofstream db;
    string fileName;
    List list;
    cout << "Enter the name of the database you want to create: \n";
    getline (cin, fileName);

    if(list.search(fileName) == false){ // means new filename, create db
        db.open(fileName.c_str());
        cout << "\nYour database " << fileName << " was created successfully\n";
        list.insert(fileName, 0);
    }
    else if(list.search(fileName) == true) { // checking if the filename is taken
        cout << "\nCould not create database because database name is already taken\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "There was a problem creating the database";
    }

    db.close();

}

void List::openDB() {
    // need to add check to see if one is already open
    ofstream db;
    string filename;
    cout << "Enter the name of the database you want to open: ";
    getline (cin, filename);

    db.open(filename.c_str());

}

void closeDB() {
    cout << "The database _______ has been closed successfully";
}

void display() {
    cout << "Enter the ID of the employee you want to display: \n";
}

void update() {

}

void report() {

}

void add() {

}

void del() {

}

int List::menu() {
    cout << "Enter the number of the operation you wish to perform (1-9)\n"
    << "1. Create new database\n"
    << "2. Open database\n"
    << "3. Close database\n"
    << "4. Display record\n"
    << "5. Update record\n"
    << "6. Create report\n"
    << "7. Add a record\n"
    << "8. Delete a record\n"
    << "9. Quit\n";

    int sel = 0;
    (std::cin >> sel).ignore();

    switch (sel) {
        case 1: createDB();
            menu(); // after creating file go back to list of options
            break;

        case 2: openDB();
            menu();
            break;

        case 3: closeDB();
            menu();
            break;

        case 4: display();
            break;

        case 5: update();
            break;

        case 6: report();
            break;

        case 7: add();
            break;

        case 8: del();
            break;

        case 9: return 0;
            break;

        default: cout << "Please try again and enter a valid number\n\n";
            menu();
            break;
    }
    return true; // to avoid error saying control may reach end of non-void function
}


int main() {
    List list;
    list.menu();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to practice implementing a link list, this would be fine. But if you just want to get the job done, you're reinventing the wheel: just put your filenames into a `std::set<std::string>`, and let `find()` do all the work for you.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems I see:

**Problem 1**

Implementation of `List::search()` is not correct. You have:

```
bool List::search(string fName){
   curr = head;

   // The initial value of match is true.
   // When the list is empty, the function will return true.
   // Not good.
   bool match = true;
   while(curr != NULL) {
      if (fName != curr->name){
         curr = curr->next;

         // It is set to false when there is no match
         // But it is not reset to true when there is a match.
         match = false;
      }
   }
   return match;
}
```

The implementation can be much simpler.

```
bool List::search(string fName){
   curr = head;
   while(curr != NULL) {
      if (fName == curr->name){

         // If a match is found, return true
         // There is no need to continue any more checks.
         return true;
      }
   }

   // If we come here, there is no match.
   // Return false.
   return false;
}
```

**Problem 2**

You are searching for the file in a new `List` each time you call `createDB()`.

You have:

```
void List::createDB() {
    ofstream db;
    string fileName;
    List list;
    ...
}
```

The line

```
   List list
```

creates a new `List` every time you call `List::createDB()`. Hence, the calls on the `list` object in that function are always on the function local object, not the object on which `createDB()` was called.

You need to use `this` instead of `list` in that function.

```
void List::createDB() {
    ofstream db;
    string fileName;

    // Don't need this.
    // List list;
    cout << "Enter the name of the database you want to create: \n";
    getline (cin, fileName);

    // Use this instead of list
    // if(list.search(fileName) == false){ // means new filename, create db
    if(this->search(fileName) == false){ // means new filename, create db
        db.open(fileName.c_str());
        cout << "\nYour database " << fileName << " was created successfully\n";

        // Use this instead of list
        // list.insert(fileName, 0);
        this->insert(fileName, 0);
    }

    // You don't really need this->search() again. That function
    // has already returned false.
    // else if(list.search(fileName) == true) { // checking if the filename is taken
    else{
        cout << "\nCould not create database because database name is already taken\n";
    }

    // This block is not needed any more.
    // else {
    //     cout << "There was a problem creating the database";
    // }

    db.close();
}
```